# I need to replace a div with another div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="abc">
        <div>
            This is the div to be replaced
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="xyz" style="display:none">
        <div>
            This is the div replaced
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've given it like this

```
$('#main').children('div:eq(0)').css('display','none')
$('#main').children('div:eq(0)').replaceWith($('#xyz').html())
```

But, if I see the output, I get it as `<div>This is the div replaced</div>` alone and not the parent div of that i.e `<div id="xyz">`

Comment: Give the exact output you get in a code comment first.

Comment: Why are you trying to replace the div at all? It seems like `show`/`hide`/`toggle` would be sufficient.

Comment: The code is replaced with the code that is *inside* the xyz-div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do what you want:

```
$('#main div:first').html($('#xyz').html())
```

Comment: `<div id="main">
       <div id="abc">
             <div id="xyz" style="display:none">
                 This is the div replaced
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>`

Comment: but i dont need the <div id="abc">

Comment: I just made that up briefly.  I'm having trouble grokking exactly what you need.  Perhaps if you could explain exactly what you would like to accomplish, I can provide some better insight.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are actually looking for toggle function.

Please check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FUmNx/)**

```
$('#main').click(function(){
    $('#main>div').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Essentially you're getting the `innerHTML` of $('#xyz'), rather than the entire tag itself.

Just do

```
$('#main').children('div:eq(0)').replaceWith($('#xyz'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var isDisplayed = $("#main").find("#abc").css("display");
if(isDisplayed == "block"){
  $("#main").find("#abc").css("display","none");
  $("#main").find("#xyz").css("display","block");
}
else{
  $("#main").find("#abc").css("display","block");
  $("#main").find("#xyz").css("display","none");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you're looking for this:

```
$('#main').children('div:eq(0)').replaceWith(xyz);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
$('#main').find('div:eq(0)').css('display','none');
$('#main').children('div:eq(0)').replaceWith($('#xyz'));
```

By specifing `$('#xyz').html()` you will only get the contents of the div.

For more info on `replaceWith` see [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Comment: this takes the html content that is inside the <div id="xyz">, but i need it including the line `<div id="xyz">`

Comment: This will also take the div #xyz, it is the .html() that takes the contents